# Query is dropping its WHERE clause with sinatra, mysql2, and activerecord

Tags: mysql, database, activerecord, sinatra, mysql2

I am having a strange issue with queries dropping their WHERE clause. Here are the gems I'm using:

- sinatra (1.4.3)
- mysql2 (0.4.1)
- activerecord (3.0.20)
- activerecord-mysql2-adapter (0.0.3)

Here is an example of what is happening. First, I query for a record and then update one of its attributes. This executes successfully.

```
IRB :> subscription = Subscription.last
IRB :> subscription.times_billed = 7
IRB :> subscription.save
```

However, here is what the mysql general query log is reporting when I save the record:

```
UPDATE `subscriptions` SET `times_billed` = 7
```

It is missing the WHERE clause. The query *should* be something like:

```
UPDATE `subscriptions` SET `times_billed` = 7 WHERE `id` = [ID]
```

This is causing every row in the table to be updated, rather than just the desired record. Somewhere in the stack, the query is being malformed.

I cannot find any other reports of something like this happening. Has anyone encountered something like this before? Please let me know if I can provide additional information.